# How to do Inline text formatting?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

For example if I have this:

```
string message = "The Quick Brown Fox";    
someTextBlock.Text = message;
```

it will show by default like this:

> The Quick Brown Fox

How to I make it show up in a TextBlock (or any element with content)?

Like this: The **Quick** Brown **Fox**

**Note:**

By "inline" I am refering to how this is done in HTML:

```
someDiv.InnerHtml = "The <b>Quick</b> Brown <b>Fox</b>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to do it in XAML like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    The <Bold>Quick</Bold> Brown <Bold>Fox</Bold> 
</TextBlock>
```

But you also can do it in code via `Inlines` property of `TextBlock`:

```
someTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "The " });
someTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "Quick ",  FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
someTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "Brown " });
someTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "Fox",  FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
```

Comment: You don't need a Run, you can use the Bold element: `The <Bold>Quick</Bold> Brown <Bold>Fox</Bold>`

Comment: Will this work in more than just a textblock?  I'm hoping for a more generic solution.

Comment: @subt13 - What do you mean by "more than just a textblock"? And in what sense you want the solution to be more generic?

Comment: @Pavlo The case I had in mind was a MessageBox.  Basically any element that allows the developer to programmatically define its text.

Comment: @subt13 - In this case `TextBlock` will do. It allows you exactly what you want - programmatically define the text. But I would not recommend going that path, it is not a true "Silverligh" way of doing things. Look for example how a `Button` allows the user to define it's content. The properties to look for are `Content` and `ContentTemplate`.